# Localizable.strings don't work after app upgrade

Tags: ios, nslocalizedstring, localizable.strings

I have app in app store which doesn't use localizable.strings. Currently I'm going to release a new version, but after 'update simulation' app doesn't see Localizable.strings. Every localized string displays as key for NSLocalizedString. What I have to do to repair it?

Comment: Can you provide some examples of how the localization was implemented?

Comment: Localization was implemented using NSLocalizedString(@"KEY", @""); I have empty comments. Localization works if I delete app before run new.